# mysql LIMIT lines with a GROUP BY operand

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a model like this (Rails 2)

```
MyModel :
- id
- category_id
- value
- my_model_count
```

I want to get the 10 first mymodels, group by their category.

It is possible with :

```
all_mymodels = MyModel.find(:all, :order => 'my_model_count')
grouped_mymodels = all_mymodels.group_by(&:category_id)
grouped_mymodels.map do|gmm|
  gmm[0...10]
end
```

The problem is that ALL the MyModel lines were returned by the query; now, there is more than 8000 lines.

Is there any method (in Rails or mySQL) to do this limit of 10 lines per group ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a straightforward single query solution to what you are looking for, but depending on your data size and what you know up front about the domain there are a few options.

First of all, you could use find_each instead which would still iterate over your complete set, but it would avoid loading all 8000 into memory.  That would look like this:

```
grouped_mymodels = {}
all_mymodels = MyModel.find_each do |model|
  grouped_models[model.category_id] ||= []
  next if grouped_models[model.category_id] > 10
  grouped_models[model.category_id] << model
end
```

Otherwise, I think you'd need to run more than one find operation to get the top ten records for each category.

If you only need some of the data from the model you could look at using GROUP_CONCAT or something else to roll it up for you too.